# PHP Bitcoin TestNet using Denpa\Bitcoin "Empty reply from server"

Tags: php, curl, bitcoin, bitcoind, bitcoin-testnet

I'm new to BTC development, so sorry if I get any key words wrong!

My Setup:

- I'm using: `https://github.com/denpamusic/php-bitcoinrpc`
- In a Laravel Application.
- I've downloaded BTC testnet locally.
- Developing on my spare PC, A windows 10, using xxamp as my Linux laptop is dead :(
- My network facing IP is 192.168.1.184, I've tried 127.0.0.1 and same issue described below.

My bitcoin.conf file

```
testnet=1
rest=1                    
txindex=1
disablewallet=1
printtoconsole=1
rpcuser=user
rpcpassword=pass
rpcallowip=192.168.1.184
```

My Main Controller method:

```
public function index()
    {
        $ip = '192.168.1.184';
        $bitcoind = new BitcoinClient('http://user:pass@'.$ip.':18333');

        $block = $bitcoind->getinfo();
        dd($block);
    }
```

When I ping my application via a web link I get this error:
`Denpa\Bitcoin\Exceptions\ConnectionException
cURL error 52: Empty reply from server (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`

And I don't know why. I've used other Api calls from this list: https://en.bitcoinwiki.org/wiki/Original_Bitcoin_client/API_calls_list and get the same result.

Is there any 'better' tutorial or BTC for dummies sites out there?

Eventually I just want to be able to Scan the ledger for incoming payments to my wallet address, then pay various people 'automatically' based on my own settings.

So my questions:

1. Any thoughts on my Empty reply issue?
2. Does anyone know if this repo can be used to send payment instructions to a wallet?

Many thanks for reading!

Comment: Update, I learned that I was using the wrong port.all RPC calls must go through 18332 (or 8332 for main BTC blockchain)

SO now I'm getting an error: `Failed to connect to 192.168.1.184 port 18332: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)`

I'm investigating rpcauth=xxx  now. I also read a similar post saying that windows 10 didn't work for this.. but I've yet to confirm

Answer (score -1):

So, I did lots of tweaking, poking and testing.. nothing worked.

I decided to just do a fresh Laravel install and just add a single package, the one listed above.. and it worked instantly.

Urgh, I love tech sometimes...